# How add values in different keys with the same name

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

here are my data :

```
{
"data": [
  {
    "date": 1577836800000,
    "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
    "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
},
{
   "date": 1577923200000,
   "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
  }
 ]
}
```

How can i add all @NOTIFICATION_OPENED" key to get all the notif opened in a same strings ? If it's not possible, how can I select only the first key "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED" ?

With my code, I print the value of the last duplicate key.

Here is my code :

```
    def create_json(id, notificationSent, notificationOpened):
return {(id):{
    'id': id,
    'notificationSent': notificationSent,
    'notificationOpened': notificationOpened,
    }}

    statUrl = 'myapiurl'
    with urlopen (statUrl) as response: sourcedata = response.read()
    statdata = json.loads (sourcedata)

   def push_data():
    newJsonx = dict()
   for item in data["data"]:
    for item in statdata["data"]:
        try:
            notificationOpened = item["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
        except:
            notificationOpened = '0'
        print(notificationOpened)
        try:
            notificationSent = item["@NOTIFICATION_SENT"]
        except:
            notificationSent = '0'
    # JSON DATA
    newJson = create_json(notificationSent, notificationOpened)
    newJsonx.update(newJson)

    with open('myfile.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(newJsonx, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

print('JSON: %s' % json.dumps(newJsonx, sort_keys=True, indent=2))

push_data()
```

Comment: Please don't post code\text as image, edit your JSON as code and remove the image. Then if you can be more clear in what output you expect from your program maybe we can help.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with your code?

Comment: I want to store the value of notification_opened

Comment: Please make an example of how you want the values be stored like, an array, an object a number.

Comment: I post all my code. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ...snipped for brevity...

with urlopen(statUrl) as response: 
    sourcedata = response.read()
    statdata = json.loads(sourcedata)

print(statdata)
# should be this format as in your question post 
# {
#     "data": [{
#                 "date": 1577836800000,
#                 "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
#                 "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
#             },
#             {
#                "date": 1577923200000,
#                "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
#             }]
# }

notificationSent = []
notificationOpened = []

for i, d in enumerate(statdata['data']):
    notificationOpened.append(d.get('@NOTIFICATION_OPENED', 0))
    notificationSent.append(d.get('@NOTIFICATION_SENT', 0))

print(sum(notificationOpened))
```

1138

Comment: thanks for your help but I get this error TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of your original code that will create the dictionary you're after.

```
# create data
statdata = {
"data": [
  {
    "date": 1577836800000,
    "@NOTIFICATION_SENT": 62629,
    "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 404
},
{
   "date": 1577923200000,
   "@NOTIFICATION_OPENED": 734
  }
 ]
}

# use your create_json function
def create_json(id, notificationSent, notificationOpened):
return {(id):{
    'id': id,
    'notificationSent': notificationSent,
    'notificationOpened': notificationOpened,
    }}

# define an ID value (needed for the create_json function)
id = 0 

# initialise output dictionary
newJsonx = dict() 

# add items to the dictionary
for elem in statdata["data"]:
    for item in elem:
        try:
            notificationOpened = elem["@NOTIFICATION_OPENED"]
        except:
            notificationOpened = '0'
        print(notificationOpened)
        try:
            notificationSent = elem["@NOTIFICATION_SENT"]
        except:
            notificationSent = '0'
       newJson = create_json(id, notificationSent, notificationOpened)
       newJsonx.update(newJson)
       id =+ 1
```

This gives:

```
newJsonx
{0: {'id': 0, 'notificationSent': 62629, 'notificationOpened': 404}, 1: {'id': 1, 'notificationSent': '0', 'notificationOpened': 734}}
```